# How to save DOB in mongodb without timezone

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am saving DOB in mongodb with new Date(), But it is storing the date with the timezone.

> new Date('02-13-1992')

> 2001-02-12 18:30:00.000Z

Comment: Yes, `Date` objects **always** include date/time and timezone, while all values are internally stored as UTC time. Do not store date values as string, it's a design flaw. Note, the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) defines date in format `YYYY-MM-DD`, thus `new Date('02-13-1992')` may create wrong date (depending on client and javascript engine).

Comment: Consider to use 3rd party data libraries like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/index.html#/?id=luxon) or [Day.js](https://day.js.org/en/), e.g. `DateTime.fromISO("1992-02-13").toJSDate()` They are much more powerful and flexible than native Javascript `Date` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Wernfried Domscheit mentioned in comments, a date is always stored with timezone in MongoDB. However, one of the canonical ways to store date in UTC timezone would be using `$dateFromParts`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  key: 1
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "dob": {
        "$dateFromParts": {
          "year": 1992,
          "month": 2,
          "day": 13
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CPzvMYUY1hA)